# Sortable lists with Symfony2 reusable

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I've rewritten this entry of the Symfony1 Cookbook http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/cookbook/1_2/en/sortable to Symfony2. My first objetive is the classic sortable list:

[image]

All the documents(MongoDB) have a position field which is integer type with the order they will be show.

I've created a service class Sortable where are the following method:

```
class Sortable
{
    //Return the position of the document
    public function getByPosition($position = 1, $document, $site, $item = null){ /**/ }

    //Return all elements sorted by position
    public function getAllByPosition($document, $site){/**/}

    //Return the max position of the items within a parent item
    public function getMaxPosition($document, $site, $parent = null){/**/}

    //Swap the position between $itemOne and $itemTwo
    public function swapWith($itemOne, $itemTwo, $document){/**/}

    //Set the new position => +1
    public function executeUp($document, $id){/**/}

    //Set the new position => -1
    public function executeDown($document, $id){/**/}

    //Persist document with the new position
    public function save($item, $document){/**/}
}
```

This works fine but the main problem is that this class is hardly reusable.

-$document var is the name of Document in database to use for example on **createQueryBuilder('MyBundle'.$document)**

-$site var is the site of my app because each user has a site.

-$parent var is of type $document and it's the parent of the documents of the same type.

The problem for me, this is hardly reusable and I've to call all methods above in the controller action and then checking the position in Twig template. I want to achieve a twig extension which call to my service and do all the logic that I do in the controller and twig. Also that it works with whatever Document.

How I can get this?